# Is there any function to convert None to empty string?

Tags: python

Something my string var is equal to `None`.
I don't want to have if statements to verify the value. Is there any simple way (like `str(my_var)`) which will return string value if this is not `None` and `''` if `None`?

Comment: Where does the `None` come from? Usually the proper solution is to fix the source of the "bad" data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `foo or ''`, but in case `foo` is any other falsy value (`0`, an empty list, etc.) it will result in an empty string, too.

Another way would be `'' if foo is None else foo`